# Upgrade 2.2 to 2.3 - unique situation, PHP Stuck at 7.2

Tags: upgrade, php-7

So, I'm on shared hosting, which works great for me, until now. My host updated PHP CLI to *7.2.15* My magento is on 2.2.6(doesn't support *7.2.15*) so I need to upgrade to **Magento 2.3**.

My issue is I have no control over PHP CLI. How can I upgrade to 2.3 with PHP CLI at 7.2.15?

Comment: You wanna upgrade via CLI or via admin

Comment: Any way possible to get me to 7.3. CLI and admin fail because my php version is too high to run the upgrade.